# Why are static variables allowed only in outer classes?

Tags: apex, class, static, inner-class

According to [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm), static variables are allowed only in outer classes. Why is that? Is it because you'd need to instantiate the inner class first?

Comment: You can read about [this subject for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727252/why-static-fields-not-final-is-restricted-in-inner-class-in-java). Though as inner classes are not given automatic access to the outer class fields in Apex not all of that is relevant.

Comment: The difference is that inner classes in java can be constructed off an instance of the outer class.  

`MyClass outer = new MyClass();
MyInnerClass inner = outer.new MyInnerClass();`

In apex, they are always treated as static on the outer class.  `MyClass.MyInnerClass inner = new MyClass.MyInnerClass();`  Thus, it seems that statics would be perfectly fine in an inner class.  I have no good answer why SF wouldn't allow them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnerClass cannot have static members because it belongs to an instance (of OuterClass) and 
a static members means that this variable belongs to the entire class and not any particular instance.